# Account Information not displaying properly onto the SalesForce VisualForce page

Tags: java, visualforce

I am newbie to the `SalesForce` and `VisualForce` pages, I write the below code but I dont see values are populating against it. Whats wrong? Any pointers?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock title="The PageBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Test" columns="1">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Balance_Fee__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name & Code" />
                <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name} ({!Account.Discount__c})" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing account ID to this page? pass it as `?id=<ACCOUNT_ID>`

Comment: Lets say I have Id=0016F00001x6N3o, how can I try when you are previewing the page?

Comment: Agree. Whenever we use `outputField`, we should always use Id. In order to print all account information, we should use `pageBlockTable`.